# Modeling subclass/superclass while maintaining relational integrity

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database

I'm trying to capture the notion of a subclass/superclass relationship in a relational database.  If I start with

```
abstract class A {
   id: UUID
}

class B extends A {
    data: String
}

class C extends A {
    data: Int
}
```

I can write:

```
create table taba (id uuid not null unique, typ char not null);
create table tabb (id uuid not null unique references taba(id), 
          data varchar);
create table tabc (id uuid not null unique references taba(id),
          data int);
```

Its relational integrity is guaranteed in one direction by the `references` clause: every derived instance B or C must have its base instance A.

But what about the other direction?  I want to guarantee that every base instance A has its derived instance B or C, and ideally that it matches the `typ` given.

I thought about doing it in a single table, like this:

```
create table taball (id uuid not null unique, typ char not null,
          b_data varchar,
          c_ data int);
```

but that seems to violate the [open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle): every time I add a new subclass of A, I have to rewrite taball.

I don't know if this is possible at all (especially because the integrity would be necessarily violated during the actual insert), but I would appreciate any suggestions?

Comment: Databases are used to organize and represent shared state. Objects are supposed to encapsulate state and abstract over its representation to focus on interfaces and responsibilities. Databases are for state, OOP is for state machines. The two concepts are orthogonal, if you conflate them, you won't get the benefits of either.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL supports [inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html) for tables so you could do the exact same thing the database as in code:

```
create table taba (id uuid not null unique);
create table tabb (data varchar) inherits (taba);
create table tabc (data int) inherits (taba);
```

This way when you insert into `tabb` or `tabc` there will also be a row available in `taba`. Depends on the situation if this is a good way to go or not.